# Как продолжить выполнение цикла, если словили исключение?

Tags: исключения, циклы, java

Здравствуйте. Имеется вот такой цикл.

```
String s;
while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Метод readLine() бросает IOException. Я могу конечно обернуть весь цикл в try-catch, но тогда при возникновении исключения цикл прервётся. Могу в методе, в котором находится этот код дописать throws IOException, но всё равно цикл прервётся. А как сделать, чтобы не прерывался? Неужели только так?

```
String s;
while (true) {
    try {
        s = in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    if(s == null) {break;}
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Это же как-то не красиво..

Comment: А вы уверены, что это в принципе возможно — после эксепшена считать строку?

Comment: @Dazar: Очень правильное замечание @Jofsey: скорее всего, если предыдущая попытка прочитать из потока привела к выбросу исключения, то и последующие попытки тоже не будут успешными, т. к. с потоком что-то не так. Поэтому игнорирование ошибки и продолжение попыток чтения приведёт скорее всего к бесконечному циклу. То есть, окружить **весь** цикл блоком try/catch, вероятно, более правильное решение.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за дополнение, полезная информация.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, только так. Если вас смущает конструкция `try/catch` внутри цикла, можете вынести её в отдельный метод, не бросающий исключений, и глушить исключения там:

```
public void doSth() {
    // ваш код

    String s;
    while (true) {
        s = readNextLine(in);
        if(s == null) {break;}
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    // ваш код
}

private String readNextLine(Reader in) {
    String s;
    try {
        s = in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return s;
}
```